# How to represent space character in JPA criteria with concat function

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I was working with a GROUP BY using JPA criteria and facing issue with concat function.

I want to represent a sql concat function in jpa like it is shown below.

```
concat(firstName,' ',lastName);
```

I tried this using jpa criteria builder as shown below.

```
cb.function("CONCAT",String.class,root.get("firstName"),cb.literal(" "),root.get("lastName"));
```

But this method doesn't work well. So I would like to know how we can represent a white space or empty string in JPA criteria?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution by myself.

We can use Hibernate `@Formula` for this purpose.

For this we will have to introduce a new dummy field and use the same mapping in select like it is given below.

```
public class UserEntity {

// other mappings for id,username,firstName,lastName here

 @Formula("nullif(concat(firstname,' ',lastname),' ')") // firstname and lastname are column names
 private String fullName;
}
```

Then use `root.get("fullName")` to retrieve full name of the user.

Answer (score 2):

There is finction in criteria bulder [concat()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#concat%28javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression%29)

```
Expression<String> e = cb.concat(root.get("firstName"), " ");
e = cb.concat(e , root.get("lastName"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately this doesn't work well when I use this with GROUP BY